# Django Rest Framework with Mozilla Django OCID

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I've been working on this Drf app to sign certificates. I have been using simple JWT for token authentication. But now I need to implement SSO authentication, so I have been trying to use Mozilla - Django - OIDC, but I can't seem to figure out the docs. I'm confused on where the access and refresh tokens would come from, since it clearly says in the docs.

```
Note that this only takes care of authenticating against an access token, and provides no options to create or renew tokens.
```

If mozilla-django-oidc is not creating the tokens, then where do I obtain them from and where will they be stored when I try to access them in my React frontend.

Thank you in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar to what you mentioning, however I was using this packages: https://django-oidc-provider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
It can effectively create tokens and authenticate, I was struggling with the validation part of the user, but... might help out.

Comment: The highest version of django is 2.0 in the requirements I am using django 4

Comment: yeah I am using 3.6. It works... barely. then stuff like that happens. I might actually to go back to that project so maybe lets keep in touch and see what both can find.

Comment: Hi James, I upgraded to django 4.1 and change the OIDC package for compactibility and it's working and live.